# Any way to setup Alerts for Twilio SMS messages by excluding a group of errors, rather than by including each error specifically?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am working on a project that encounters a series of errors everyday such as user unsubscribed, etc. (About 4 or 5 different error codes everyday)

These errors are inconsequential to the management and can be ignored.

Any way to configure the alerts on Twilio to email me when any error occurs which DOES NOT belong to the error group that is deemed inconsequential?

Doesn't have to be email, new to this and open to any savvy ways of keeping myself informed of new errors in an automated way.

As far as I can tell, I can only perform the opposite action(Setup 1 alert for each error code) on the Twilio code. This has the disadvantage of having to know the error code in advance before configuring the alert.

Open to any way of doing this, not just through the console(via a Python API etc.)

Thank you.

[image: Twilio alert setup page]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Can I suggest that you set up the event webhook as shown here:

[image]

It will send a webhook event to a server of yours for every error or warning that is triggered. You could then build a small service that receives those errors and discards the ones you don't care about and alerts you of ones that do matter.

On top of that, you can change the threshold of the error emails. If you always get 4-5 errors a day, making the alert threshold 6 errors may alert you if something is wrong that you don't expect.

Finally, the errors may be inconsequential, but you might find it easier to try to drive those errors to 0 every day anyway. If they are due to unsubscribed phone numbers, ensure to disable sending messages to those numbers once you detect that they are unsubscribed.